# If Ax = b has a solution then (A^2)x = b has a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I cant seem to find a way to prove it because:

if Ax = b has a solution then we know that if we multiply on left side by matrix A we will get A(Ax) = Ab
witch then we can replace Ax by b so Ab = Ab holds true.

but i am not sure this means the linear equations (A^2)x = b has a solution.

Comment: Hint: consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: If $Ax =b$ then $A^2x =A(Ax)=Ab=b$. Therefore we have this kind of solution when $b$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue equal to $1$. But, as already shown, it is not true in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prove it as the statement is not true for all instances of $A$ and $b$. For example, let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and let $b= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $Ax=b$ has a solution. But what about the equation $A^2x=b$? In fact, can you note that the matrix $A^2$ is $0$.

Comment: yea then it has no solution for the A squared, thanks!